# ArcGIS - How to programmatically create new dynamic layer for service?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I'm trying to create a number of widgets that will visualise different data by geographic area, e.g., the *Potential Losses for Instrument X in Year Y for the Counties of State Z.*

Ideally this would be a map of the state (tick can do that)
with the showing the county boarders (use javascript api to display basemap layer )
and then colour each county according to loss. :(

Going down the ArcGIS route I am assuming I need to create a dynamic layer here with all of the polygons for each county of each state defined and then somehow colour them according to data pulled out of a DB showing loss for that instrument, for that county for that year.

Could someone please

- A) validate that that is the correct way to go and
- B) point me in the right direction to some resources to help me learn
  how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may not fully understand your question, but it may be simpler than you think.

You can do a lot with symbolization of the layer in the mxd before publishing as a map service. It's quite easy. Harder to do fancy symbolization with javascript. See "About symbolizing layers to represent quantity" http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/About_symbolizing_layers_to_represent_quantity/00s500000034000000/

Easiest and best performance would be to have a county polygon layer with the attributes you are describing added to it, but you could also take a county layer and then "join" or "relate" a regular db table to it -- I'm using the ArcGIS terms for a database join.

Then in a web map, you can define a popup that could display additional attributes for each county. See
http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/samples/widget_popupfl/index.html and there are several similar examples.

Comment: Hi awesomo, I have a moved away using ArcGIS to solve this solution but your answer does seem to cover most of the bases I was after. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Mostly right! Instead of a Dynamic Layer, you'll need to create a "time-aware" Feature Layer.  A good example of what (I think) you're looking for is here:

http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jssamples_start.htm#jssamples/time_snapshot.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. I am not really after an interactive chart just a service which I can pass some parameters into ie Instrument X, Year Y, State Z and for it to query the DB and produce the chart accordingly. - Once I have the chart I can see how to use the javascript API to display it. It is the developing  the layer - the bit which  says Charlotte County in Florida had a loss of 10K for this year so colour it blue that I don't know how to do. Presumably I start off with a basechart defining the polygons for each county & state but then I get lost

Comment: Do you have all this information (Instrument X, Year Y, County/State Z) in a database right now?

Comment: Hi Mintx, yes I have all the data but have now had to take a non ArcGIS approach - and thus have moved on to this question here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43014/creating-responsive-interaction-with-tiled-maps

Comment: Excellent! If you answer your own question and mark this one answered, that would be great! We're trying to keep unanswered questions low around here. :)