# Creating responsive interaction with tiled maps

Tags: polygon, tiles, maps

I think I may have two conflicting aims but...

I need to create responsive Choropleth map very similar to  http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html or 
http://www.texastribune.org/library/data/us-senate-runoff-results-map/

I need to take it down to county level of detail - like the texastribune example - but unlike the two examples above I cannot restrict the map to either a state or even a country. It has to have the show the detail globally.

To describe the whole world in GeoJson polygons down to the county/ postal area level would involve shipping an insane amount of data to the browser which has taken me down the route of using tiles and leaflet.js to orchestrate. This works well for providing a basic Choropleth map but I can't then see a way to display the additional data when you mouse over an area.

Is there any hybrid way of getting the best of both worlds

Comment: Just to clarify, you need an interactive map that covers the globe at a county level? If so... holy cow. :O